# Not able to activate tagged vlan on Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, vlan

I'm not able to get tagged vlan running on my box. Any idea?

```
$ ip link add link eth0 name eth0.666 type vlan id 666
$ ip addr add 10.10.10.10/24 dev eth0.666
```

I don't get any failure but interface is not up.

The module is loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep "8021q"
8021q                  23888  0 
garp                   13188  1 8021q
mrp                    13274  1 8021q
```

Any idea what went wrong? How I might can debug that better?

Update: I was able to add an IP with ifconfig command:

```
ifconfig eth0.666 10.10.10.10/24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I was able to add an IP with ifconfig command:

```
ifconfig eth0.666 10.10.10.10/24
```